# How to write MYSQL query with GROUP BY Clause for HOUR where if NO data for particular hour, Return 0

Tags: mysql

I want to write MYSQL query to fetch data, Where I want to count SMS sent per hour bases GROUP BY the HOUR where if there is NO data for a particular hour, It should return 0.

Also, I want to Count data for the first 9 hours and last 3 hours together likewise I mentioned in expected result, the first row is 00：00～09：00 and the last row is   21：00～24：00

I would like to mention that I searched StackOverflow a lot for the question and didn't found my answer

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) , DATE_FORMAT( sms_sent.register_time,  '%H:%i:%s' ) AS SENT_TIME
FROM sms_sent
WHERE sms_sent.sent_by =9998
AND DATE( sms_sent.register_time ) =  '2018-12-27'
GROUP BY HOUR( sms_sent.register_time ) 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

What expect is that

```
Sent Time       Sent Count
00：00～09：00     0
09：00～10：00     0
10：00～11：00     0
11：00～12：00     0
12：00～13：00     0
13：00～14：00     0
14：00～15：00     0
15：00～16：00     0
16：00～17：00     0
17：00～18：00     0
18：00～19：00     0
19：00～20：00     0
20：00～21：00     0
21：00～24：00     0
```

What I am getting this time is :

[image: Current Result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an `hours` table, to generate all the hours in the day. Then you can create your periods of interest from that, and also `JOIN` it to your SMS data to get the count of SMS for each period. This query should give the results you want:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN hours.hour < 9 then '00:00-09:00'
            WHEN hours.hour >= 21 then '21:00-24:00'
            ELSE concat(lpad(hours.hour, 2, '0'), ':00-', lpad(hours.hour+1, 2, '0'), ':00')
            END AS period,
       COUNT(ss.register_time) AS `Sent Count`
FROM (SELECT n10.n * 10 + n.n as hour
      FROM (SELECT 0 AS n UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2) n10
      JOIN (SELECT 0 AS n UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4
            UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) n
      WHERE n10.n * 10 + n.n < 24) hours
LEFT JOIN sms_sent ss ON HOUR(ss.register_time) = hours.hour AND ss.sent_by = 9998 AND DATE(ss.register_time) = '2018-12-27'
GROUP BY period
```

Output (for the demo data I created):

```
period          Sent Count
00:00-09:00     3
09:00-10:00     0
10:00-11:00     0
11:00-12:00     1
12:00-13:00     0
13:00-14:00     0
14:00-15:00     1
15:00-16:00     2
16:00-17:00     0
17:00-18:00     0
18:00-19:00     1
19:00-20:00     0
20:00-21:00     0
21:00-24:00     1
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=4b02d367c650d155b6cbc6759cb0ddb9)